# Why maven wants to check remote availability for a pom present in local repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

I was given a zip file with the content of another user's maven local repository (`~/.m2/repository`) and then I was given a zip file with a maven project.

If I go into the project (`com.foo.my.project`) and run `mvn -X clean install` it fails to download from maven central repository a custom library pom (`com.foo.bar`):

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /home/user/apache-maven-3.5.2/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/user/.m2/settings.xml
[...]
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/user/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/user/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of /home/user/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/1.0.0/bar-1.0.0.pom from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.foo.my.project:project:4.2.1: Failure to find com.foo:bar:pom:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13
```

I can I tell maven to not attempt to check remote availability of a **custom package** which is only present in local repository?

Comment: This is the automatic behaviour of maven. If it is in the local repository, it takes it from there.

Comment: @JFabianMeier if you read correctly you find out that this is the behaviour I'm looking for, but maven doesn't behave like expected.

Comment: I just wanted to say that there is nothing you need to configure for Maven to do this. If it does not work in your case, then there is probably a typo somewhere, a broken local repository or you used a SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: @JFabianMeier In my opinion the log `Verifying availability of /home/user/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/1.0.0/bar-1.0.0.pom from [central ..` removes any doubt about typos or snapshots. It's clearly not a SNAPSHOT, and there is no typos as the pom in local repository it's correctly found. Still maven tries to check an online version

Comment: Then please show us the content of the respective folder in your local repository.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file /home/user/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/1.0.0/_remote.repositories and any SHA files in that folder and rerun the maven build command.